# Laravel 5.8: Trying to get property 'order' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am working on a Laravel 5.8 project which is an Online Store. and in this project, I wanted to add "Printing Order Factors" feature for Admins.

So I have made a form like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('orders.newprint') }}">
    @csrf
    @forelse($orders as $order)
    <tr>
        <td><input class="form-check-input" name="orderCheck[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $order->ord_id }}">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>{{ $order->ord_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->status_label }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->customer_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->ord_total }}</td>
    </tr>
    @empty
        <td colspan="7" class="text-center">No order to show</td>
    @endforelse
</form>
```

So basically admins can select multiple orders like this:

[image]

And I'm trying to send order ids as an array:

`<input class="form-check-input" name="orderCheck[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $order->ord_id }}">`

So after clicking *Print All Order Factors*, it should be showing **all the order factors at one page**.

So in order to do that, I have added this method at the Controller:

```
public function prnpriview(Request $request)
    {
        $args = [];
        $orders = $request->input('orderCheck');
        foreach($orders as $ord){
            $order = Order::find($ord);
            $args[] = [
                'order'  => $order,
                'address'  => $order->order_address->first(),
                'details'  => $order->orderDetail,
                'sendType'  => $order->productSubmit,
                'coupons'  => $this->cartController->computeDiscountForOutRequests($order->ord_object_id, $order->ord_creator_id),
                'user'      => User::query()->find($order->ord_creator_id)
            ];

        }
        return view('admin.shop.orders.newprint', compact('args'));
    }
```

Then at the Blade, I tried out this:

```
 @foreach($args as $arg)
    <p>Buyer Name:
        <strong>
            {{ $arg->order->customer_name }}
        </strong>
    </p>
    <p>Address:
        <strong>
            {{ $arg->address->province_relation->prv_name }}،
            {{ $arg->address->city_relation->cit_name }}،
            {{ $arg->address->address }}
        </strong>
    </p>
    ...
@endforeach
```

But I get this error:

> Trying to get property 'order' of non-object (View: newprint.blade.php)

Comment: Well ... you are forming $args as a multidimensional array and not as an array of objects. Test using array syntax. Ie: `@foreach($args as $arg) {{ $arg['order']->customer_name }}`

Comment: Thank u man. You may put that as answer. @porloscerrosΨ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you are forming `$args` as a multidimensional array and not as an array of objects.

So in your view you should use array syntax.

Ie:

```
@foreach($args as $arg) 
    {{ $arg['order']->customer_name }}
    {{ $arg['address']->province_relation->prv_name }}،
// ... and so
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Since suggestions are appreciated, this part could be improved:

> ```
>     foreach($orders as $ord){
>         $order = Order::find($ord);
>         $args[] = [
>             'order'  => $order,
>             'address'  => $order->order_address->first(),
>             'details'  => $order->orderDetail,
>             'sendType'  => $order->productSubmit,
>             'coupons'  => $this->cartController->computeDiscountForOutRequests($order->ord_object_id, $order->ord_creator_id),
>             'user'      => User::query()->find($order->ord_creator_id)
>         ];
>
>     }
> ```

You could have just use `find()` outside the loop to reduce time complexity. Since `find()` DOES accept `array` as parameter in Laravel core:

src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php

```
  public function find($id, $columns = ['*'])
    {
        if (is_array($id) || $id instanceof Arrayable) {
            return $this->findMany($id, $columns);
        }

        return $this->whereKey($id)->first($columns);
    }
```

So you may want something like this:

```
$order = Order::find($request->input('orderCheck'));
foreach($orders as $ord){        
    $args[] = [
        'order'  => $order,
        'address'  => $order->order_address->first(),
        'details'  => $order->orderDetail,
        'sendType'  => $order->productSubmit,
        'coupons'  => $this->cartController->computeDiscountForOutRequests($order->ord_object_id, $order->ord_creator_id),
        'user'      => User::query()->find($order->ord_creator_id)
    ];
}
```

Now the complexity is `O(n)` in place of `O(n^2)` I suppose.